# Cloudflare frequently Error 523

Tags: hosting, cdn, cloudflare

I am using cloudflare as the CDN to optimize my website traffic. However, I am frequently experience issue that the website appear with the error message saying "Error 523: Origin is unreachable". The error occur very frequently and randomly. Meaning, when the error occur, I just need to refresh the page and it will be OK already.

What causes it? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a post in cloudflare's site for this : https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171946-Error-523-Origin-is-unreachable

Probably your issue is the communication between your hosting provider and cloudflare servers

Comment: if you are on a shared server  , you might use more resources than you permit to (if your site has too many traffic) and hosting provider may apply some limits to your account

Answer (score 0):

Try switching off Railgun (you can find it under the 'Speed' tab). I've experienced similar issues and they were all related to Railgun. Official support won't admit it, but in my experience, Railgun is buggy and unreliable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I am using the FREE Cloudflare which don't have Railgun. So, I doubt it is caused by it for my case here. What do you think any other possibility?

Comment: @user1995781 Are you sure? I'm on the free plan too and I did have Railgun enabled. I was a paid customer before, maybe that caused the trouble?